# How to show that a integrable function is finite a.e.?

Tags: measure-theory

I want to show that an integrable function is finite a.e.

Then I have to show that if 
$$\int fd\mu<\infty \implies \mu(\{x\mid |f(x)|=\infty \})=0$$
for a measure $\mu$.

My idea is:

$$\{x\mid |f(x)|=\infty \}=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\{x\mid |f(x)|\geq k\}$$

Moreover, there exist a sequence a simple function $\{\varphi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb N}$ with $\varphi_n>0$ for all $n$ such that $\varphi_n(x)\nearrow |f(x)|$ for almost every $x$. Therefore
$$\{x\mid \varphi_n(x)\geq k\}\nearrow \{x\mid |f(x)|\geq k \}$$
and thus 
$$\{x\mid |f(x)|\geq k\}=\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty \{x\mid \varphi_n(x)\geq k\}.$$

Finally, we get
$$\{x\mid |f(x)|=\infty \}=\bigcap_{k\in\mathbb N}\bigcup_{n=k}^\infty \{x\mid \varphi_n(x)\geq k\}.$$

Now I want to use Borel-Cantelli, but how to prove that $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \mu(A_n)<\infty$$

where $A_n=\{x\mid \varphi_n(x)\geq k\}$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition an integrable function has finite absolute integral, i.e. if $f\in L^1(X,\Sigma, \mu)$ then

$$\int_X |f|\,d\mu<\infty$$

however, if $B\in\Sigma$ is the set for which $|f|=\infty$, we have by monotonicity that

$$\infty\cdot\mu(B)=\int_B |f|<\int_X |f|$$

hence, unless $\mu(B)=0$ we have a contradiction to absolute integrability of $f$.

If you're not comfortable with instantiation of infinity, you can see that

$$f_n\cdot 1_B\equiv n\nearrow f\cdot 1_b$$ is a monotone sequence of integrable functions converging up to $f$ on $B$. If you still have the issue that $\mu(B)=\infty$ might be an issue, then cut down to a finite, postive measure subset and again use monotonicity. That is to say you can say there is a positive, finite measure subset of $B$, $B'$ on which $f=\infty$ and then

$$f_n\cdot 1_{B'}\nearrow f\cdot 1_{B'}$$

so that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{B'} f_n\,d\mu=n\cdot \mu(B')\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\infty =\int_{B'}|f|\,d\mu<\int_X |f|\,d\mu$$

Comment: tks for your quick answer, but could you tell me how to conclude in my proof ?